# My merge sort is not ordering correctly

Tags: c++, sorting, merge

So i've for a school project i've been assigned to implement a merge sort from a pseudo code given by the professor. This is what i came up with, in my use case, 
instead of ordering:
    0 1 4 5 9
it orders it:
    5 4 1 0 9

My use case: 
    5 9 1 0 5 4

here is the merge part of the merge sort and the global variables

```
long long intercambio;
int aux[5555], arr[555];

void merge(int begin, int middle, int end) {
    int i = begin, j = middle+1, k = begin, temp;
    while (i <= middle && j <= end) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
            aux[k] = arr[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            aux[k] = arr[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
        noSwaps++;
    }
    if (i > middle) {
        while (j <= end) {
            if (aux[k -1] > arr[j]) {
                temp = aux[k - 1];
                aux[k - 1] = arr[j];
                aux[k] = temp;
                noSwaps++;
            }
            else {
                aux[k] = arr[j];
            }
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    else {
        while (i <= middle) {
            if (aux[k -1] > arr[i]) {
                temp = aux[k - 1];
                aux[k - 1] = arr[i];
                aux[k] = temp;
                noSwaps++;
            }
            else {
                aux[k] = arr[i];
            }
            k++;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here i call recursively the merge sort

```
void mergeSort(int begin, int end) {
    if (begin < end) {
        int middle = (begin + end) / 2;
        mergeSort(begin, middle);
        mergeSort(middle + 1, end);
        merge(begin, middle, end);
    }
}
```

This is the main class

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        int len;

        cin >> len;
        while (len != 0) {

            for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
                cin >> arr[x];

            noSwaps = 0;

            mergeSort(0, len - 1);
            for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
                cout << aux[x] << " ";
            cout << endl;

            cout << noSwaps << endl;

            cin >> len;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I think translating code names into english could help to understand code people who doesnt know spanish

Comment: Sorry about that. Translated to english variables names.

Comment: The proper translation is `begin , middle , end`, not `start , half , end`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why your code inside the `if (i > middle)` block and its `else` block are so complicated. All you have to do is copy the remaining elements into `aux`, and then from `aux` back to `arr`:

```
void merge(int begin, int middle, int end) {
    int i = begin, j = middle+1, k = begin, temp;
    while (i <= middle && j <= end) {
        // ... same as before ...
    }
    while (i <= middle)
    {
        aux[k++] = arr[i++];
    }
    while (j <= end)
    {
        aux[k++] = arr[j++];
    }
    for (i = begin; i <= end; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = aux[i];
    }
}
```

This may or may not be less (or more) efficient than your solution, but at least it works :)

By the way, there is a cute trick to implementing merge sort where you don't have to worry about exhausting one range before the other. You copy the left range to `aux` in ascending order, and the right range in descending order. Then you start merging from both ends, and when the indexes meet, both ranges are exhausted:

```
void merge(int begin, int middle, int end)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = begin; i <= middle; ++i)
    {
        aux[i] = arr[i];
    }
    for (j = end; j > middle; --j, ++i)
    {
        aux[i] = arr[j];
    }
    i = begin;
    j = end;
    k = begin;
    while (i <= j)
    {
        arr[k++] = aux[(aux[i] < aux[j]) ? i++ : j--];
    }
}
```

This solution appears to produce the wrong output, but only because there is a bug inside `main`:

```
for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
    cout << aux[x] << " ";
```

You are printing `aux`, when in fact you should be printing `arr`:

```
for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
    cout << arr[x] << " ";
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixes the ordering and makes the implementation very beautiful. But I still have a problem, my teacher asked us to keep the number of swaps in the merge sort as low as possible, and return it. With his sample input '5 9 1 0 5 4 0 ' the sample output for the number of swaps is 6. In your solutions the number of swaps is higher, is there anyway to keep it low?